# ng-change is throwing error [$compile:ctreq]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs 1.2.14, the code is working fine without ng-change.
As soon as i add the code for ng-change in checkbox. it throws the error.

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
at Error (native).....
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide more information. For example, JSfiddle or Plunker.

Comment: Or at least provide the code ? Unless you believe that `ng-change` is broken in 1.2.14 (which is clearly not the case), it is quite remarkable that you want us to find the error in your code without providing the code !

Comment: I tried to write a sample code for you which is smaller version of my actual code. But it is having some other error. You can see the code http://jsfiddle.net/fzS6L/ I am very new to AngularJS so i am not sure where am i getting wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

to use `ng-change` in your element you should also specify `ng-model` which i had missed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9):

http://plnkr.co/edit/oF8o6kU7zBDaJg4ts6TU?p=preview

See working sample.

ng-change requires ng-model, without it will not work